# Dynamically set height of an EditText based on the content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an Edit text in which i am using setText to load the data on an edit form. Currently the editText height is fixed and if the text Is larger than the editText height i can't see the full text at once.
 Is there a way based on the content i can dynamically set the height of an EditText.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions

Regards
R

Comment: show me  your xml code for edittext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting the height of edit text as  following :

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code for your xml file:

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/edtFirstName"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:hint="@string/first_name"
   android:padding="5dp"
   android:textColor="@color/black"
   android:textSize="16sp" />
```

while your edit text contain comes it automatically fit the text size.

**Do not use** `android:singleLine="true"` or `android:minLines="1"` and `android:maxLines="1"`

Answer (score 2):

Set **`android:layout_height`** [**`wrap_content`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#WRAP_CONTENT) is best Approach .

> The view should be only big enough to enclose its content .

Use [**`DisplayMetrics`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)  for **Dynamically** set the height of an **EditText**.

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

**How ?**

```
if(length()>n) // n is your String length
editTEXT.getLayoutParams().height=DeviceTotalHeight*10/100;
```

Answer (score 2):

This may help you,

Using **`android:layout_height ="wrap_content"`** and **`android:inputType="textMultiLine"`** are best approach

```
 <EditText
    android:id ="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:hint ="Hint"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
```

I will suggest you to use **`ScrollView`** as a parent layout of **`EditText`**

It prevents your `EditText` to cut off (outside from the screen) from screen when you have a larger `text`

Answer (score 1):

Try, this one may help -:

```
  edittext.getLayoutParams().width=50
```

---

```
    et= (CustomEditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = et.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = 100;
    lp.height = 100;
    et.setLayoutParams(lp);
```